# How to generate a bean class for a SOAP web request for Jersey framework in java

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jersey-2.0

I'm using eBay notification API, i'm getting a SOAP web request that contains XML inside.

I would like to use jersey framework in order to deserialize the request into an object.

Is there any easy way to generate a bean class from the SOAP request that will be used in a simpler way that I'm using `json`? for an example :

```
@POST
@Path("/path")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response methodName(Item bean)
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate bean class from xml response using JAXB library. 
[Read More about this](http://theopentutorials.com/post/uncategorized/generate-java-class-from-xml-schema-in-eclipse-ide/)